# Copying files to a remote server in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I am configuring a Jenkins job and Jenkins slave is installed in a windows server(A). I want to copy project build output folder to another windows server(B).

I can execute a batch file manually on Server A, with following content.

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command Copy-Item "C:\Jenkins\workspace\DEV_Build\DEPLOY\UAT\build" -Destination "\\SYDUATAPP01\E$\build" -recurse
```

However, when I execute this batch file through Jenkins I get a error "Access Denied"

```
Access is denied
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAcces 
   sException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Pow 
   erShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Appreciate your help..... If it is not possible via powershell, I would like to know what other alternatives I have to copy files in my Jenkins job

Comment: try by destination filesystem::"$yourpath"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gergard, Thank you very much for your help. I tried putting the provided bit of code to run as admin. However, nothing worked. Execution policy was remotesigned.

Finally below steps solved my problem;

- I installed Powershell plugin(1.3) on my windows remote slave. Powershell 1.3, executed with "ByPass" policy
- And added a step from powershell to copy item.

  Copy-Item "source path" -Destination "\destination path" -recurse
- Above steps didn't solve the issue and still complained as unauthorized.
- Then I configured jenkins remote slave process -> properties -> run as admin account.

This solved the issue and now I am able to copy files successfully.

Answer (score 1):

As admin, check if you have the `-executionpolicy` set as intended

```
powershell get-executionpolicy
```

if not then as admin, run:

```
powershell set-executionpolicy remotesigned -force
```

Then I am not 100% sure why you want to run this as a batch file, but instead just save it as a .ps1 file.

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Jenkins\workspace\DEV_Build\DEPLOY\UAT\build" -Destination "\\SYDUATAPP01\E$\build" -recurse
```

where you can also use  `-Force -PassThru -Verbose`

If you still want to run it as batch file, then just run

```
powershell Copy-Item -Path "C:\Jenkins\workspace\DEV_Build\DEPLOY\UAT\build" -Destination "\\\SYDUATAPP01\E$\build" -recurse
```

**EDIT** To run your script as admin, you can copy this into the very top of your script. It basically just creates a VBS file that launches the batch as admin. Initially it will popup the UAC prompt, but it is a once of deal, from there it will run the script as admin each time.

```
@echo off 
 >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
   if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Checking privileges.
    goto UPrompt
      ) else ( goto Admin )
:UPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\Admin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\Admin.vbs"

    "%temp%\Admin.vbs"
    exit /B
:Admin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\Admin.vbs" )
     pushd "%CD%"
     CD /D "%~dp0"
:----------------- Copy the rest of your Batch below this line------
```

Comment: I executed "powershell get-executionpolicy" in both FROM and TO servers where I copy files. both commands returns "Unrestricted". I modified batch command as you suggested which includes three back slashes in the to path. Now it gives out "Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\\SYDUATAPP01\E$\mdh' is denied."

Comment: And as admin, I set executionpolicy to Bypass, still gets the access denied

Comment: you need to run cmd as administrator. right click on cmd.exe and select `run as administrator`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gerhard. I'm executing this batch file via Jenkins. So that, i can't run it manually as admin. I tried -verb RunAs, but it didn't work

Comment: `powershell set-executionpolicy remotesigned -force` needs to run only once and does not need to form part of the script. Just open cmd.exe as administrator and run the command once, once it is set, the script should work without the `powershell set-executionpolicy remotesigned -force` part. Alternatively. I have another part of a script which you add to the very top of your batch file that will run your script as admin, but should not need to. once you tried this, let me know, else I will post the top part of the batch.

Comment: Edited script. First try the comment above, else put the last portion in the answer at the very top of your batch file.